# Pandas pivot table int32 overflow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm currently trying to create a pivot table using Pandas' `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` method and am experiencing some problems.

The DataFrame that I have is of shape `(1300000, 6)` and so the resulting pivot table is probably going to be very large. The specific error that I get is:

```
ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow
```

A (failed) solution that I came up with was to split the DataFrame into smaller DataFrames, create pivot tables with those, and then concatenate those pivot tables to create the original large pivot table I wanted to.

The problem is that the shapes of the pivot tables are different for each slice, as I'm calling `df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2')['col3']` and the values of each column will be different from slice to slice. Just for reference, the pivot table that I made with the first 100 rows is of size `(62, 63)` whereas the pivot table I made with the first half of the original DataFrame gives me the error:

```
*** MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (13218, 389275) and data type object
```

Does anybody have any idea on how I could circumvent this problem?

In case anyone's wondering on why I insist on creating pivot tables, I'm currently working with a team and their entire code is based on the assumption that there is a pivot table to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading your datasource in chunks.

Ex: read_csv has an attribute: chunksize.

Details in pandas documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html