# How to get a value from another column based on the value of one column in an efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas

This question is motivated by my previous question - [Pandas pivot table int32 overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043455/pandas-pivot-table-int32-overflow). The motivation is that since I cannot make a complete pivot table due to the size of my dataset, I'll create the data objects one row at a time as I go.

To be a bit more specific, the original idea or intuition behind using the pivot table is that there are three main columns in our original dataset that we want to make use of. Let's call them `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` for the sake of convenience. The original idea was the make the rows of the pivot table correspond to the unique values in `col1`, and columns correspond to the unique values in `col2`, and the entries to correspond to the value of `col3` when a pair from `col1` and `col2` would appear in the same row in the original dataset.

If I were to give a toy example:

```
# Original Dataset
       Day      Fruit      Quantity
0    Monday     apple         3
1    Tuesday    banana        2
2    Monday     banana        5
3    Friday     apple         7
4    Thursday   orange        9
5    Tuesday    orange        0

# Pivot Table
           apple    banana    orange
Monday       3        5         0
Tuesday      0        2         0
Thursday     0        0         9
Friday       7        0         0
```

The code that I'm using to perform this operation is as follows:

```
data_values = []
day = days[0] # e.g. Monday

for fruit in fruits: # apple, banana, orange
    df = original_df.loc[original_df['Fruit'] == fruit]

    if day in df['days'].values:
        data_values.append(df['Quantity'])
    else:
        data_values.append(0)
```

The code works, but it takes a very long time (the original DataFrame has a size of `(1327481, 6)` and the pivot table is estimated to be of size `(679003, 5536)` since there are 679,003 unique values in `col1` and 5,536 unique values in `col2`).

Does anybody know of a way that I can do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do to get pivot table column by column, and it should be a lot faster:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['Day'].unique(), columns=['Day'])
for fruit in df['Fruit'].unique():
    new_df = new_df.merge(df.loc[df['Fruit'] == fruit, ('Day', 'Quantity')].groupby('Day', as_index=False)\
                   .sum().rename({'Quantity': fruit}, axis=1), how='left')
new_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get a memory error at the first line. :(

Comment: @Seankala You mean inside the loop?

Comment: No, I mean declaring the new template DataFrame itself. Considering that the number of rows is 680,000 and columns is around 5,500 I would have a DataFrame with a total of 3,740,000,000 entries. I suppose it is rather big. I'm not sure how I need to go about this though. Perhaps slicing the DataFrame into muhc smaller pieces is the only possible solution, but the problem is that the number of columns wouldn't be the same.

Comment: @Seankala You are not doing something right, or you didn't describe the problem right. `df[some_col].unique()` is a 1-d list with a maximum length of the number of rows in your dataframe. So it makes no sense that you have enough memory for the entire `dataframe`, but not for a 1-d list with the unique values of one of the columns.

Comment: Ah apologies, I read your code wrong the first time. Let me try again and I'll let you know!

Comment: Hmm... This method actually takes longer than my original. My original method took around 5 minutes for one row but your suggested one took around 9.

Comment: @Seankala Interesting, but are you sure your 5 minutes code peform the same output as my code? Because what you posted here just creates a list of numbers. I assumed you wrapped it somehow to eventually get the pivot table, but I would expect the entire process in your code would be much longer than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
import pandas as pd
file=pd.read_excel("test.xls")

df=file.values

test=[]

for data in df:

```
  temp=[]
  if len(test)>0:
        for dt in test:
              if data[0] in dt:
                    if data[1]=="apple":
                          dt[1]=data[2]
                    elif data[1]=="banana":
                          dt[2]=data[2]
                    elif data[1]=="orange":
                          dt[3]=data[2]
                    break
        else:
              temp.append(data[0])
              if data[1]=="apple":
                    temp.append(data[2])
              else:
                    temp.append(0)
              if data[1]=="banana":
                    temp.append(data[2])
              else:
                    temp.append(0)
              if data[1]=="orange":
                    temp.append(data[2])
              else:
                    temp.append(0)
             # break
        if len(temp)>0:
              test.append(temp)

  else:
        temp.append(data[0])
        if data[1]=="apple":
              temp.append(data[2])
        else:
              temp.append(0)
        if data[1]=="banana":
              temp.append(data[2])
        else:
              temp.append(0)
        if data[1]=="orange":
              temp.append(data[2])
        else:
              temp.append(0)
        if len(temp)>0:
              test.append(temp)
```

df=pd.DataFrame(test)
print(df)

I hope it will work.

Comment: Apart from the fact the looping the rows in a `pandas` dataframe is the slowest last-resort-only solution possible, he wrote he has 5,536 values in his true 'col2'. Do you expect him to write 5,536 `elif`s?

Comment: Yes that's right,but i just tried for improving myself.Your answer was awesome to see.I was not expect it will be solve within 6 lines of code.stunning..keep rocking